# ViewPager error: Unable to start activity component

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-xml

**ViewPagerFragment.java**

```
package nsixty.crew.app;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class ViewPagerFragment extends FragmentActivity {

    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

    ViewPager pager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setContentView(R.layout.lcmeter);

        this.initialisePaging();
    }

    private void initialisePaging() {

        List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

        fragments
                .add(Fragment.instantiate(this, LoginActivity.class.getName()));
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, send.class.getName()));
        this.mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(
                super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);

    }

    public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private List<Fragment> fragments;

        public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.fragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return this.fragments.get(position);
        }

    }

}
```

**lcmeter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+android:id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Androidmanifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="nsixty.crew.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <support-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon87"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity android:name="ViewPagerFragment" >

            <!--
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            -->

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="nsixty.crew.app.main" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".play"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="nsixty.crew.app.play" />

                <category
                    android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
                    android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".secondView"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="nsixty.crew.app.SECONDVIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".recorder"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="nsixty.crew.app.RECORD" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".send"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <!-- android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="nsixty.crew.app.SHARE" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".gallery"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="nsixty.crew.app.gallery" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".media"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="nsixty.crew.app.media" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" >
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

</manifest>
```

**LogCat**

```
08-28 11:28:34.149: E/AndroidRuntime(18946): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-28 11:28:34.149: E/AndroidRuntime(18946): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nsixty.crew.app/nsixty.crew.app.ViewPagerFragment}: java.lang.ClassCastException: nsixty.crew.app.LoginActivity
08-28 11:28:34.149: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1664)
08-28 11:28:34.149: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1680)
08-28 11:28:34.149: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-28 11:28:34.149: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
08-28 11:28:34.149: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-28 11:28:34.149: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-28 11:28:34.149: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3703)
08-28 11:28:34.149: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 11:28:34.149: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-28 11:28:34.149: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
08-28 11:28:34.149: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
08-28 11:28:34.149: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-28 11:28:34.149: E/AndroidRuntime(18946): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: nsixty.crew.app.LoginActivity
08-28 11:28:34.149: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:388)
08-28 11:28:34.149: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:363)
08-28 11:28:34.149: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at nsixty.crew.app.ViewPagerFragment.initialisePaging(ViewPagerFragment.java:35)
08-28 11:28:34.149: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at nsixty.crew.app.ViewPagerFragment.onCreate(ViewPagerFragment.java:28)
08-28 11:28:34.149: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-28 11:28:34.149: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1628)
08-28 11:28:34.149: E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    ... 11 more
```

My LoginActivity class and send class works fine if am running the application normally without ViewPager. So i didn't add the code of those classes here. am just trying to make my app more stylish that's why am using view pager
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think LoginActivity is extending Activity class rather than Fragment class. That is why you are getting classcastException. The class needs to be a Fragment

Comment: Ok i change loginactivity to extend to FragmentActivity and send to extend to FragmentActivity. i still get the same error. maybe i didnt get you, can you plz explain again. thanks

Comment: you need to extend Fragment not FragmentActivity

Comment: if i extend Fragment i get so many errors especially on findviewbyid

Comment: Yeah, fragment and activity are not same, it needs a different approach. Thr are a lot of tutorials on So

Comment: Ok thanks i figured it out, most of it u use getActivity.watever u trying to convert to fragment. The app is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Below is entry in your manifest file.

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity" >
```

You can't extend LoginActivity from Activity  and instantiate it .. it must be extending Fragment .

Comment: Ok i change loginactivity to extend to FragmentActivity and send to extend to FragmentActivity. i still get the same error. maybe i didnt get you, can you plz explain again. thanks